# Referencing an Entity column using a string variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation

I'm trying to create data driven validation for my application that uses Entity Framework.
In my Validation table I want to store the:

- Field Name(FreightToBillCustomer)
- Validation Condition (>)
- Validation Value (5)
- Error Message (Freight to bill customer must be    less than 5)
- Member Name(FreightToBillCustomer)

I will utilize these in the following.

```
if (  FreightToBillCustomer > 5)
{ 
    ValidationResult vr = new ValidationResult("Freight to bill customer must  be less than 5",new[] { "FreightToBillCustomer" });
    errors.Add(vr);
}
```

My problem comes when I pass in the Field Name as a string variable, how can I translate/convert to a column that entity framework recognizes.  My goal is to get a list of validation records and loop though them in the partial class for the entity and perform the validation before the SaveChanges() event.

Comment: There's nothing special about the objects you persist to Entity Framework. They are plain objects that EF will treat in a certain way when you load or save them. This means that you can use the same Reflection or  Expression techniques you would with any other POCO. Check the existing validation libraries, eg [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) before building your own

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  I'm new to WPF and Entity Framework so please forgive me if what I ask for seems simple.  I looked into FluentValidation and that opens up a whole new world.  I still don't see how to convert a string variable to an entity framework column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
var assembly = typeof(NameOfAnyClassInTheAssembly).Assembly;

string typeName = NameOfClass;
var type = assembly.GetType(typeName);

// Create an instance of this type
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Get the property of this type
var property = type.GetProperty("NameOfProperty");

// Fetch the property value
var propertyValue = property.GetValue(instance, null);
```

Just replace the NameOf.... variables with your variables.

See the following link for a working example:

[Reflection example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-property)

Comment: Yup. Just use plain ol' reflection.

Comment: That is great, thanks for the lesson.  My only issue now is how do I get the value out of the property.  For example, if I'm doing my validation and the field < 5, how do I get the value of the property to make sure it's less than 5.
Thanks in advance for helping out this newbie.

Comment: Use something like var propertyValue = property.GetValue(instance, null) to fetch the property value. I have added the code to my answer.

Comment: I'm getting a null when know there is a value.

Comment: I have added a link to a reflection example that works at the bottom of my answer.